# Using if in SQL Server based on IF function condition from Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for help to convert the `IF` format below to be used in SQL Server:

```
=IF((MID(A1,3,1))="1","SS"&(MID(A1,1,2)),"FW"&(MID(A1,1,2)))
```

The column of the table I am trying to use instead of A1 will be `Data_Code`, willing to have the Data_Code result will be either SS or FW, I did create a small column below for the original data:

```
|Data_Code|
|221484848|
|222848488|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this `=IF((MID(A1,3,1))="1","SS"&(MID(A1,1,2)),"FW"&(MID(A1,1,2)))` comes from Excel. You can use `CASE` expression to check the value, and `SUBSTRING` function for `MID` like this:

```
SELECT CASE SUBSTRING(Data_Code, 3,1) 
         WHEN '1' THEN 'SS' 
         ELSE 'FW' 
       END + SUBSTRING(Data_Code, 1,2) [MyNewColumn]
FROM [ExampleTable]
```

Comment: Hi , appreciated your kind support; it work exactly how I was looking for; thx

Comment: just have a curious question if I have a sum and I want to group by based on the [MyNewColumn] is it possible or only I should group it by the original column name?

Comment: @YoussiMizrahi you need a sub-query to make use of your calculated column for anything other than an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @Dale K, honestly i did try it Select ( [MyNewColumn] = the above Query sample ( select Sum(Quantity) from [MyTable] group by [myNewColumn] ; and it did not work would you kindly advice if possible?

Comment: Please ask a new question and provide sample data, desired results and your attempt.